# How to execute JS code after redirect to page with href link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I have a page with a function like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "checkLogin.php"
   })
   .done(function( msg ) {
      alert(msg );
      if (msg != "true"){
         window.location.replace("index.html");
      }
});
```

This function checks if a Session is alive on Server. If not it will redirect to index.html.

On first call of this .html it works. But if I go to this page with a href link when the page was loaded before the page isn't executing any JS.

How can I call that JS again?

When I am open up an other page without loading that page with javascript before and click the href link it works.

Something with Cache?

Comment: I guess try using location.href,  replace() removes the URL of the current document from the document history, meaning that it is not possible to go back?

Comment: Thank you, that is doing the trick. 
It was possible to go back but no JS was executed then. 

Is there a more nicer way to do that? Not in Link on other page. On the page where the JS is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `window.location.replace("index.html");` `replace()` removes the URL of the current document from the document history, meaning that it is not possible to go back.

Comment: If I do that on a.html and the command is "window.location.replace("a.html");" i'll build a loop over that page over and over again.
Did I get your tip wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is append the index.html string with index.htlm#something and then detect that (something) onload/on document-ready for the index page, and execute the code you want

edit: ie `window.location.replace("index.html#session_check");`

and on the index page, use

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("#session_check") != -1) {
// code here
}
```

Comment: Thank you this works too, but not so useful in my case, because the other JS isn't executed, too. I would have to "duplicate" all code for that.

Answer (score 0):

According to my limited knowledge JS scripts from a different HTML file are not executed due to security reasons. If you want to execute the JS scripts you need to use the **eval(str)** function call. Where str is the JS scripts serialized to a string. 
A second approach would be to create a **"script"** tag dynamically and supply the **src** attribute pointing to the desired JS file. When the script tag is placed in the DOM the script should hopefully be executed.